# data not loading in rapid angularjs prototype

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a quick prototype and the data doesn't load. What could it be? I 've added a fiddle too:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container" ng-app="usersApp" ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='client in clients'>
        <td>{{ client.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.percentage }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('clientsApp').controller('ClientsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clients = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 25, percentage: 0.3 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 39, percentage: 0.18 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jude', age: 51, percentage: 0.54 },
    { id: 4, name: 'James', age: 18, percentage: 0.32 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Javier', age: 47, percentage: 0.14 }
  ];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gb3n6xjg/

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Always use double quotes in HTML i.e. `ng-repeat="client in clients"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You have several issues:

**1)** You have your 'clientsApp' module declared wrong.

`angular.module('clientsApp')`  should be `angular.module('clientsApp',[])`

**2)** Also you are not calling the correct module with your `ng-app` directive.

`ng-app="usersApp"`  should be `ng-app="clientsApp"`

**3)** To use angularjs in JSFiddle you also need to change the run mode from **onLoad** to **No Wrap - in**

---

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/1t940eum/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that caused it to not work:.

1. The name of the app (`clientsApp`) and the name of the controller (`ClientsCtrl`) were different in the markup and the JavaScript. See the corrected markup within the code snippet
2. You were not declaring the module named `clientsApp`. You first need to declare it before you can add a controller to it using this syntax

`angular.module('clientsApp', []);`

3. On the fiddle, the Angular library was being loaded using the `onload` event - I changed it to `No wrap - in <body>` to get it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/crm1rw35/)

```js
angular.module('clientsApp', []);
angular.module('clientsApp').controller('ClientsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clients = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    percentage: 0.3
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 39,
    percentage: 0.18
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jude',
    age: 51,
    percentage: 0.54
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'James',
    age: 18,
    percentage: 0.32
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Javier',
    age: 47,
    percentage: 0.14
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="clientsApp" ng-controller="ClientsCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Percentage</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='client in clients'>
          <td>{{ client.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ client.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ client.percentage }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```